# Connect sql default username with python

Tags: sql-server, python-2.7, pypyodbc

I'm trying to connect sql server to python script when I try to make a new username it doesn't work when i try to connect to it by the managment studio it doesn't run only with the default username SQLEXPRESS i don't know how to connect i tried to use pypyodbc

```
    database = pypyodbc.connect('Driver=SQL Server;Server=localhost;Database=Database.db;uid=MSSQLSERVER;pwd=')
```

it raises an error    **Access is denied or server not found**

Comment: Try `r'Driver={SQL Server};Server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS; ...'`

Comment: Thank you, but from where can i find the uid and pwd